# Linux sendfile() then overwrite the file, sendfile() send overwritten data

Tags: linux, mmap, sendfile

I am developing a program by read data from disk and sent to network socket.

I use `memfd_create()` to create a memory file as buffer and get the `mem_fd`, use `ftruncate()` to set the file size, and `mmap()` to map the buffer address `buf`.

The program repeatedly read data **into** `buf`, and sent `mem_fd` using `sendfile()`. When `sendfile()` call returns, the return value is checked (it says all data has been sent), then new data starts overwrite into `buf`.

But I found the data may be wrong sometimes, it looks like `sendfile()` sending the overwritten data rather than the old data.

Comment: I found this article https://systemsnotes.wordpress.com/2013/03/24/sendfile-on-memory-mapped-files/